# What can I hook into after_setup_theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, hooks, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I'm wondering what can I or should I NOT hook to `after_setup_theme`? I'm wondering because I have been told that I shouldn't hook `wp_enqueue_style` to it, but I have seen other places using it to hook `wp_enqueue_script` here: http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/12/30/wordpress-theme-function-files

From what I understand this is just stuff that is theme dependent, so confused on why I shouldn't use `wp_enqueue_style` in it?

Can I chuck stuff like this in there too?

```
add_action('get_header', 'enable_threaded_comments');
add_action('widgets_init', 'unregister_default_wp_widgets', 1);
remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of WordPress execution as a series of rungs on a ladder: WordPress climbs one rung, then the next, then the next, and so on.

Think of action hooks as the rungs themselves. [Here is a (slightly abbreviated, I think) list of those actions, or "rungs" executed during a typical WordPress request.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request)

Thus, an `add_action()` call is simply an instruction to execute a function on a specific rung on the ladder. As long as you *make* that `add_action()` call on a rung *earlier* than the run on which you want the specified function to *execute*, then it doesn't matter, *per se* which rung you use to *make* the `add_action()` call. However, there *are* reasons to use specific rungs to *execute functions*.

To take your example: a Theme's `functions.php` file executes at (I believe) `after_setup_theme`. So, you simply can't use a Theme to add an action to any rung *prior to* `after_setup_theme`, because WordPress has already executed those actions (i.e. WordPress has already climbed those "rungs" on the ladder).

If you try to execute `wp_enqueue_script()` in a callback hooked into an action *before `init`*, WordPress will generate a `_doing_it_wrong()` notice, because `wp_enqueue_script()` should not be executed before `init`, and most correctly *should* be executed at either `wp_enqueue_scripts` (front end) or `admin_enqueue_scripts-{hook}` (admin).

However:

> Can I chuck stuff like this in there too?
>
> ```
> add_action('get_header', 'enable_threaded_comments');
> add_action('widgets_init', 'unregister_default_wp_widgets', 1);
> remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
> ```

All of these are perfectly fine being called at `after_setup_theme`, since all of the specified actions fire *later than* `after_setup_theme`. With `add_action()`, you're simply telling WordPress, "*queue up this callback at the specified action*." With `remove_action()`, you're simply telling WordPress, "*remove this callback from the specified action*."

#### Edit

In re:

> Great answer - thanks. I understand most of it, but a little confused why all my calls to hooks with the `add_action` and `remove_action` are ok but the call to `wp_enqueue_scripts` isn't? They all fire after `after_setup_theme`. I know you said it's because I can't execute `wp_enqueue_scripts` before `init`; though without you telling me that how would I know? For example, how do I know if there is anything else that can't be executed before something else.

Because `add_action()` simply *queues up* a callback, inside of which functions are actually executed. But functions like `wp_enqueue_script()` or `wp_enqueue_style()` are actually *functions*, that *execute* wherever you call them.

Comment: Great answer - thanks. I understand most of it, but a little confused why all my calls to hooks with the `add_action` and `remove_action` are ok but the call to `wp_enqueue_scripts` isn't? They all fire after `after_setup_theme`. I know you said it's because I can't execute `wp_enqueue_scripts` before `init`; though without you telling me that how would I know? For example, how do I know if there is anything else that can't be executed before something else.

Comment: See updated answer. The difference is that `add_action()` doesn't execute anything, but `wp_enqueue_script()` does.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to check how other themes use `after_setup_theme` hook to get general idea, check [functions.php](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/functions.php) of themes like Twenty Eleven and Underscores (_s).

`after_setup_theme` is mainly used to load theme functionality files, register support for various features like, post thumbnails and post formats, load translation files, etc. You can also register action and filter on theme setup, but I like keeping them near the callback functions.

`wp_enqueue_script()` and `wp_enqueue_style()` function should be hooked into appropriate action - `wp_enqueue_scripts`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't hook wp_enqueue_style function calls into that because other action hooks exist that are more appropriate.

Specifically, if you need to do enqueue-ing on the front end of the site, you should hook to the "wp_enqueue_scripts" hook. If you need to enqueue something on the admin-side of the site, you should hook to the "admin_enqueue_scripts" hook.